# Generate a 2d data matrix image in c#

Tags: c#, 2d, barcode

I am pretty much a beginner in c#. I got a task to generate a 16mm X 16mm barcode by reading a 20 character length alphanumeric code. It should generate 2D data matrix image. Can someone help me out in this where to begin and how to approach. I read couple of tutorials, but was not able to crack it down. Please help me with step by step tutorial for the same. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply download the library given [here](http://www.onbarcode.com/tutorial/csharp-barcode-generation.html) and follow the tutorial given on the same page.